# How to check if two strings are the same

Tags: python

H guys

silly question but one that is confusing me

```
print test
print test == "None"
```

in the terminal this prints out

```
None
False
```

as you can see test is None, but the check to see if they are the same comes back false

why is this ?

Comment: None is not a string, it's a `NoneType`.

Comment: Try printing `type(test)`

Comment: `print test == None` should give `True` although it's generally suggested to use `print test is None` for this type of test.

Comment: Ah thanks guys, sorry first few days coding python

Comment: Why is this voted down? The question is clear to me, and just because the answer is trivial to many of us, doesn't make it a bad question.

Comment: @BartFriederichs by definition: *This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*. No research effort and it's not useful. Plus it *lacks minimal understanding*.

Comment: If one of the answers helped, be sure to mark it as correct to help out the answerer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python then `None` is a data type, so where you can have a number, or a string, you can also have None.

In your case, to check if it's `None` just remove the quotes:

```
print test == None
```

But you got the principle for testing if two strings are the same right:

```
test = "Hello"
print test
print test == "Hello"
```

Gives:

```
Hello
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
print test
print test == "None"
print test == None
print type(test)
```

Comment: You always should compare with `is` to `None`.

Comment: Yes, but the point was to show that the result is True. Introducing a new operator is probably not the best idea given the question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you assigned the string `"None"` to `test`. It's likely that `test` is a `NoneType` so you should test it like this:

```
print test is None
```

The result is the same as `test == None` but the [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says that you should use the keyword `is` instead of `==` to test for equality of singleton objects, like `None`.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `None` is not a string, it is of type `NoneType`. Compare it to other languages 'null'. The string with value `"None"` is not the same as `None`.

Perhaps the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html) can help you more.